# Notebooks can be specified via a relative path (./Notebook or ../folder/Notebook)

Tags: python, databricks

I am trying to run a  databricks notebook to databricks  another notebook. However, I got an error.

Notebooks can be specified via a relative path (./Notebook or ../folder/Notebook) or via an absolute path (/Abs/Path/to/Notebook). Make sure you are specifying the path correctly.

Here's what I tried:

```
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().get()

%run ./MainFolder/TasksFolder/UtilitiesFolder/utilities_nb
```

But, still got that error. Any tips on this one? Thanks for inputs, much appreciated!

Comment: Just curious - from which notebook are you trying to run which notebook ? The first command would give the path of the current notebook...Also please ensure that the items mentioned in the note section in this [link](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#use-run-to-import-a-notebook) are being followed where applicable.

Answer (score 1):

The run command here specifies the path inside your current working directory or folder where the master-notebook (the notebook from where you are calling the function). This is due to the `.` in the start (which indicates present working directory)

If you want to provide the absolute path, please remove the `.` from the beginning to something like this

```
/MainFolder/TasksFolder/UtilitiesFolder/utilities_nb
```

I am not sure if this is your absolute path. (You can copy the absoulute path by right-clicking on the `utilites_nb` too)