# %run "./Includes/Classroom-Setup"

Tags: databricks

I'm learning Databricks v3 course, while executing the cells I'm getting below error

```
Notebook not found: Users/Includes/classroom-setup-4.1-setup. 
Notebooks can be specified via a relative path (./Notebook or ../folder/Notebook) 
  or via an absolute path (/Abs/Path/to/Notebook). 
Make sure you are specifying the path correctly.

Stacktrace:
  /Users/user@gmail.com/DE 4.1 - Querying Files Directly: sql
```

I have attached notebook to the active cluster, I don't have Includes folder in my workspace under Users/

Please help me to get these Includes.

Tried in Databricks Notebook

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notebooks can be specified via a relative path (./Notebook or ../folder/Notebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75754557/notebooks-can-be-specified-via-a-relative-path-notebook-or-folder-notebook)